# WPF; Convert simple string into my TextBlock Text failed and due to Cannot find resource named

Tags: wpf, converters, textblock, mahapps.metro

So i have this `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock 
    Name="tbVersion"
    Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}}"/>
```

Converter:

```
public class TextConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "bla bla";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And i got this error when try to run my application:

> {"Cannot find resource named 'TextConverter'. Resource names are case
>   sensitive."}

Although there is no compiler errors at all and i declare this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Convertors:TextConverter x:Key="TextConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Ok so i try to take another `Converter` that works from another `TextBlobk` and still got this error that cannot find resource although this exist (and works as i mentioned...) so maybe because my `TextBlobk` is inside `DataTemplate` :

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock 
                Name="tbVersion"
                Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you post the xaml where declare the converter? Is it inside a `ResourceDictionary` and/or the `Resource` tag?

Comment: Please see my update, this declared inside Window.Resources

Comment: its working for me! what is the namespace where your Converter is defined

Comment: Ok i found something that maybe is the reason for this, please see my update now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: tested code]
As you can see from the image, i used exactly your code, and is working just fine.

So you may have added the converter to Window.Resources but you are using it in a different ResourceDictionary?

If you want to make them globally usable you should add them to the App.xaml, or programmatically to the Application.Current.ResourceDictionary

**EDIT:**

Try adding the converter to the DataTemplate.Resources

Comment: i am using this TextBlock in my main XAML and the Converter declare in the same XAML inside indow.Resources

Comment: This TextBlock is declare at the same XAML inside the mahapps TitleTemplate, please see my update